# PJRC Encoder Object as Property of Another Object

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm borrowing [PJRC's Encoder library](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Encoder.html) to manage a stepper-powered syringe pump I am running off a [Sparkfun RedBoard](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12757) and a [BigEasy Driver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12859).

I've been developing the program modularly, defining lower-level classes first and working up from there. It is my *desire* that higher-level classes take instances of lower classes as properties. In my current nightmare, I'm building a syringe Pump class with Stepper motor and Encoder objects as properties.

I'm organizing the library into a header file and '.cpp' file as recommended by the Arduino Tutorials. The Pump class is declared as follows in 'Pump.h':

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Stepper.h"
#include "Encoder.h"

#define PUMP_TOP_SPEED 50   // ml/min               top pump speed
#define PUMP_ERROR 10       // encoder counts       acceptable error

class Pump {

    private:

        Stepper motor;          // object       stepper motor
        Encoder encoder;        // object       attached encoder
        int countPerRev;        // #            encoder counts per relovlution
        float nominalVolume;    // mL           nominal syringe volume
        float innerDiameter;    // cm           syringe inner diameter
        float shaftLead;        // cm           driveshaft threading lead distance
        float degVolume;        // mL           effective volume change per degree of rotation
        bool state;             // boolean      T = ready, F = slept

    public:

        // constructor
        Pump(const Stepper& stp, const Encoder& enc, int cpr, float vol, float diam, float lead);

        float volume();                         // returns nominalVolume
        float position();                       // returns current pump position in mL
        void hold();                            // high power state to resist back-pressure
        void relax();                           // low power state
        void pump(float vol, float rate);       // pumps the requested volume at requested rate
        void release();                         // moves the plunger all the way out so syringe can be serviced
        void set();                             // returns plunger to zero mL
};
```

The relevant code in 'Pump.cpp' file which I have been testing with is the constructor and the definition of the `pump()` method, which goes like so:

```
// constructor
Pump::Pump(const Stepper& stp, const Encoder& enc, int cpr, float vol, float diam, float lead) : motor(stp), encoder(enc), countPerRev(cpr), nominalVolume(vol), innerDiameter(diam), shaftLead(lead) {

    // calculate volume per degree
    // (diameter^2 / 4) * PI * (lead / 360) = mL / deg
    // diam * diam * lead * PI / 360 / 4 = (diam diam lead PI) / 1440
    degVolume = innerDiameter * innerDiameter * shaftLead * PI / 1440;

    // construct the encoder inside here
    /*encoder = new(Encoder(2,3));

    // set it to 0
    encoder.write(0);*/
}

// pumping function
void Pump::pump(float vol, float rate) {

    /*
        vol < 0         INFUSE
        vol > 0         WITHDRAW
    */

    if (rate > PUMP_TOP_SPEED) rate = PUMP_TOP_SPEED; // limit rate

    if (!state) hold(); // wake up the motor if it's asleep

    // make sure this doesn't push outside of the acceptable range
    if (position() + vol <= nominalVolume && position() + vol >= 0) {

        // (mL) / (mL/deg) = deg
        float degrees = vol / degVolume; // find number of degrees to turn the motor
        Serial.print("Looking to turn ");
        Serial.print(degrees, DEC);
        Serial.print(" degrees at ");

        // (count) + (deg) * (count/rev) / (deg/rev) = count
        long goal = encoder.read() + degrees * countPerRev / 360; // set target encoder reading

        // (mL/min) / (mL/deg) / (deg/rev) = RPM
        int rpm = abs(rate) / degVolume / 360; // find RPM to turn the motor
        Serial.print(rpm, DEC);
        Serial.println(" RPM in full-stepping mode");
        Serial.print("Going from encoder count ");
        Serial.print(encoder.read(), DEC);
        Serial.print(" to ");
        Serial.println(goal, DEC);

        motor.drive(degrees, 1, rpm); // drive the pump

        int err = goal - encoder.read(); // how far from the goal are we in counts?
        Serial.print("Reached encoder count ");
        Serial.println(encoder.read(), DEC);
        Serial.print("Missed by ");
        Serial.println(err, DEC);

    }
}
```

I've been testing my `pump()` method and threw in a whole bunch of `Serial.print()` to try to debug and figure out what is happening and from what I can see, the Encoder object that is a **property of the Pump object** doesn't have its position updated as the shaft turns, whereas the Encoder object **declared in the Arduino sketch** and passed to the Pump constructor does.

As you can see above I've tried to initialize the encoder within the pump constructor but the 2 or 3 things I tried all threw a bunch of cryptic errors in the Arduino IDE when I tried to compile, left that commented out section so you can see what I was trying.

What I find exceedingly annoying is that while my own Stepper object works fine, the Pump object can turn the motor, the Encoder object won't function inside the Pump object. When I run the sketch:

```
#include <Stepper.h>
#include <Encoder.h>
#include <Pump.h>

// initialize stepper
Stepper motor(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);

// initialize encoder
Encoder encoder(2, 3);

// initialize the pump
Pump pump(motor, encoder, 1440, 25, 2.328, 0.1);

void setup() {
  // start the Serial connection
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // set up the motor
  motor.enable();
  motor.reset();

  // pump
  pump.pump(0.25,25);

  Serial.print("Pump reading:       ");
  Serial.println(pump.position(), DEC);
  Serial.print("Encoder reading:    ");
  Serial.println(encoder.read(), DEC);

  // cool boards
  pump.relax();

}

void loop() {}
```

I get back the following in the Serial monitor:

```
Looking to turn 211.4397277832 degrees at 58 RPM in full-stepping mode
Going from encoder count 0 to 845
Reached encoder count 0
Missed by 845
Pump reading:       0.0000000000
Encoder reading:    845
```

So, the method `encoder.read()` always returns zero in the Pump object but when I called it at the end of my sketch in the `setup()` function it turns I turned exactly as far as I wanted to.

Thank you for reading. I'd appreciate guidance on how to either properly pass an active Encoder object to Pump, or how to properly initialize an Encoder object within Pump without freaking out the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The key was, in-fact, to initialize the encoder within the Pump object, as I've been reading on the Arduino boards posted by people some variant of my issue.

I constructed the encoder within the property declarations of 'Pump.h'. Since the [RedBoard](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12757) I'm working with is an Arduino Uno, in essence, the only acceptable pins are 2 and 3 for interrupts. I declared the encoder with the following line under the class's list of private properties:

```
Encoder encoder = Encoder(2,3);     //  attached encoder
```

And it now works flawlessly. There is likely an option to pass the encoder pins to the Pump constructor and have it be flexible, but for the time being I need something that works more than I need something perfect.